# Three way Eloquent relationship definition and saving in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a Laravel app (with Vue3 and InertiaJS), and I'm attempting to create relationships between three models:

- User
- Area
- WorkHours

where `WorkHours` is the primary model. In addition to the main data (date, hours, comments, reason), I need to create the following relationships:

1. User - the `WorkHours` entry is for work performed by the member (aka `User`), so I need to be able to see total hours for the user for the year. One user can have many `WorkHours` records.
2. Area - The part of the club that the work hours has been performed in/for. Each `WorkHours` entry has one approver, and one approver can be associated with many `WorkHours` entries.
3. Approver - Every `Area` has specific people that can approve `WorkHours` entries, and these are defined as `approvers` in the `Area` model related to the `User` model as `approver_id` (a `belongstoMany()` relationship both ways). Each `WorkHours` entry has one approver, but one approver can be associated with many `WorkHours` entries.

It seems then that the `work_hours` table should have `_id` values for each of the three relations (`user_id`, `area_id`, and `approver_id`). However, as I read the [Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), that means that `WorkHours` would be a child of both `Area` and `Approver` via `belongsTo()`, since the child gets the `_id` value of the parent.

So with all that here's the code:

**work_hours migrations**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('work_hours', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('area_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('approver_id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->decimal('hours', 5, 2);
            $table->string('reason')->nullable();
            $table->string('comments')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

            $table->foreign('approver_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

            $table->foreign('area_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('areas');
        });
    }
```

**WorkHours**

```
class WorkHours extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'date',
        'hours',
        'reason',
        'comments'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function approver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'approver_id');
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }
}
```

**Area**

```
class Area extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function approvers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'area_user', 'area_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function workHours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WorkHours::class);
    }
}
```

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function workHours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WorkHours::class);
    }

    public function areas() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Area::class);
    }

    public function approval()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(WorkHours::class, 'approver_id');
    }
}
```

Now where I'm running into the problem is saving everything when I submit my form to my controller.  From my form I have the following pieces of info

- user_id
- area_id
- approver_id
- date
- hours
- reason
- comments

So based on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships), I would think I would do something like this in `WorkHoursController`:

```
    public function store(StoreWorkHoursRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $user = User::find($validated['user']);
        $area = Area::find($validated['area']);
        $approver = User::find($validated['approver']);

        $wh = WorkHours::make([
            'date' => $validated['date'],
            'hours' => $validated['hours'],
            'reason' => $validated['reason'],
            'comments' => $validated['comments']
        ]);

        $wh->user()->associate($user);
        $wh->area()->associate($area);
        $wh->approver()->associate($approver);

        return Redirect::route('workHours.index')->with('success', 'Work Hours saved');
    }
```

but I get an error about `user_id not having a default value`, which is true, since my understanding is that Eloquent handles assigning that. What I can do is make `user_id`, `approver_id`, and `area_id` fillable in the `WorkHours` model and save like this:

```
        $wh = WorkHours::create([
            'date' => $validated['date'],
            'hours' => $validated['hours'],
            'reason' => $validated['reason'],
            'comments' => $validated['comments'],
            'user_id' => $validated['user'],
            'approver_id' => $validated['approver'],
            'area_id' => $validated['area']
        ]);
```

and it works, but it is cloogy, and bypasses Eloquent.

1. Do I have my relationships set up properly for what I am trying to accomplish?
2. How do I need to store the records in my controller to properly use Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue (as I suspected) was in a relationship definition. Once I changed the `approval()` definition in `User` from this

```
    public function approval()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(WorkHours::class, 'approver_id');
    }
```

to this

```
    public function approvals()
    {
        return $this->haMany(WorkHours::class, 'approver_id');
    }
```

it worked fine. There was no user id value to write since the relationship for the `approver` was wrong, which was why it was looking for a default value.